# SQL Query for SELECT CASE

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm building an email form to email our sales team based on who they chose the email to go to.

I'm trying to build my CASEs with query to pull data from my database instead of having to physically write out each instance of the sales team.

````
```     
            <% Select Case ContactEmail %>
              <% Case "1" %><% TeamName="Austin General Sales" & TeamEmail="austin@XX.com"%>
              <% Case "2" %><% TeamName="San Antonio General Sales" & TeamEmail="sanantonio@XX.com"%>
<%
'Declare variables
Dim oConn1, oRS1, mySQL1

Set oConn1=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRS1=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oConn1.Open(myDSN)

mySQL1 = "SELECT SalesTeam.* FROM SalesTeam WHERE (IsManager=0) ORDER BY SalesTeam.StoreID"

oRS1.open mySQL1, oConn1,1,3

If Not oRS1.EOF Then
Do While not oRS1.eof

Name=oRS1("SalesTeam.Name")
Email=oRS1("SalesTeam.Email")
MemberID=oRS1("TeamMemberID")

    %>
              <% Case & " " & MemberID %><% TeamName=Name & TeamEmail=Email%>
    <%
oRS1.movenext
Loop
End if
oRS1.Close
Set oRS1=nothing
oConn1.Close
Set oConn1=nothing
%>

            <% End Select %>
````

````
But, its giving me this error:

    ```
        Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0400'

    Expected statement

    /incmodules/ContactForm.asp, line 72

    Case & " " & MemberID
    ```
````

Comment: Hello, welcome to [so]. Please take a few minutes to familiarise yourself with the formatting tools then [edit] the question and use them to tidy up (code formatting, indentation etc.) the post.

Comment: Where does `MemberID` come from, it's not defined the code anywhere? Please try to provide enough code to allow us to reliably test it ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

`Select Case` for each its case expects a value for test expression and that's why it fails on `Case & " " & MemberID` which is neither value  nor proper syntax.

The syntax of a Select Statement in VBScript is

```
Select Case expression
Case value1
      ...
Case value2
      ... 
Case Else
      ...
End Select
```

You seem to have a sub-case, and you can do

```
Select Case expression
Case value1
      ...
Case value2
      ...

   Select Case expression2
   Case value1
        ...
   Case value2
        ... 
   Case Else
        ...
   End Select          

Case Else
      ...
End Select
```

or simply

```
if ContactEmail=1 then
   ...
else 

   Select Case expression
   Case value1
        ...
   Case value2
        ... 
   Case Else
        ...
   End Select 

end if
```

which perhaps will be more simple and clear.

Comment: While this is a good answer, the code has more issues then just this. For example trying to use `If` and `Do While Loop` statements in the middle of a `Select Case` boundary.